# _flutter is not defined error in index.js - Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting

So the error occurs only after I `firebase deploy` the web folder of my Flutter app. Below are some helpful screenshots.

The app is just a simple app that only displays an image. It works well in dev mode. I manually put the image in `./web/assets` as well in an attempt to debug.

The output on the live website is a total blank page with the below errors. The browser header title is correct though.

[image: the error]
[image: the file structure]
[image: firebase.json]

I think basically the browser is looking for a route/file called '/flutter.js'. What can cause this? This does not happen in another simple app that I built with Firebase and Flutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deployed the `web` folder instead of the `build/web` folder

Comment: I am getting the same issue even after deploying from the `build/web` folder

Comment: Can you give a bit more details ?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to build your project @ShailendraMadda?

Comment: That issue is resolved long time back, I do not remember what exactly I did @samuelnihoul